# My schema markup Rentalcarreservation not works when I receive at my gmail

Tags: gmail, schema, google-calendar-api, html-email, google-schemas

I attach this html markup code with http://schema.org/RentalCarReservation to my email template when a customer make a booking online. 
I validate this markup at https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/
and not returns any validation error. You can try it.

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/RentalCarReservation" style="display:none"><span itemprop="reservationNumber">161129-125729</span> <a href="http://schema.org/Confirmed" itemprop="reservationStatus">a</a>

<div itemprop="underName" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span itemprop="name">Fran Deve</span></div>

<div itemprop="reservationFor" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/RentalCar"><span itemprop="name">Fiat 500</span> <span itemprop="model">500</span>

<div itemprop="brand" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Brand"><span itemprop="name">Fiat</span></div>

<div itemprop="rentalCompany" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"><span itemprop="name">Centauro Rent a Car</span></div>
</div>

<div itemprop="pickupLocation" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Place"><span itemprop="name">Centauro Rent a Car Barcelona - Aeropuerto</span>

<div itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress"><span itemprop="addressLocality">Barcelona - Aeropuerto</span></div>
</div>
<span itemprop="pickupTime">2017-01-12T09:00:00.000Z</span>

<div itemprop="dropoffLocation" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Place"><span itemprop="name">Centauro Rent a Car Barcelona - Aeropuerto</span>

<div itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress"><span itemprop="addressLocality">Barcelona - Aeropuerto</span></div>
</div>
<span itemprop="dropoffTime">2017-01-19T09:00:00.000Z</span>
```

Then I open my gmail or google now and nothing happens. I make sure that have my  Google Calendar settings with "Events from Gmail" with "add automaticly" checked.

Comment: Hi,

I find this post:
https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1710607

That if I write "my reservations" on google shows the list of reservations.

This code works fine but I'm talking with Google support member waiting her response for a admin panel that shows all my bookings or any more schema markup email.

Comment: I tried the testing your markup, unfortunately, it did not parse in Inbox. You may want to follow the microdata examples provided in the documentation (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/rental-car).